# one model not reloading rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an old model amongst many that has not been touched in years.  I am adding some new methods today, and discover that after making changes this model does not reload.  Every other model I try works fine.  I.e. I go into a model and make a small useless change, and refresh a page, and it all works.

Except for this particular model, which is named Coupon (coupon.rb).

I am seeing nothing signficantly different about this model.  It inherits from active record base, just like everybody else, etc etc.

I have even tried deleting all lines except

```
# encoding: UTF-8
class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

to no avail...

What could be causing this?  Its making debugging this a pain!

If nobody knows an answer, is there a quick work around to force this file to recompile? So I can at least get on with life?

Comment: check if there's another class like Coupon.

Comment: do you have another constant called Coupon in the system? Are you doing anything fancy in the loading of this Coupon class?

Comment: a global search for Coupon (case sensitive) revealed nothing.  And no we are not doing any special loading of the Coupon class.

Comment: check `config.cache_classes = false` in environment/development.rb

Comment: i would just point out that comment above could not apply since as noted other modules / classes were not being cached.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can happen when you bypass the automatic loading (through require_dependency) and just start requiring or loading files explicitly. My guess is somewhere in your codebase you have a  "require 'coupon'" or "load 'coupon'". Remove those and just let rails load it.

Comment: This was exactly the problem.  A require 'coupon' was left over from rails 2.x days, and because coupon.rb had never been edited....  Thanks!